# Assigning bean value in @PostConstruct

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

In the example below, I need to assign to Bean2 an attribute of Bean1. The attribute is `null` (see below). Also,  "@PostConstruct Bean2" is printed before "After assignment".

Is there a way to make sure that Bean2 instance is created before assigning the value in Bean1?

```
@Stateless
public class Bean1 {

    @Inject
    private Bean2 bean2;

    String x;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
         x = "Some Value";
         System.out.println("Before assignment");
         bean2.setX(x);
         System.out.println("After assignment");
    }
}

@Stateless
public class Bean2 {

    private String x;

    public setX(String x) {
         this.x = x;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        System.out.println("@PostConstruct Bean2");
        System.out.println(x);  // <-- x is null
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behavior based on how you've set things up.  `x` should be properly set in `Bean2` after the entire applicationContext has been spun up.

To understand what's going on, notice that `Bean2` is a dependency for `Bean1`.  That means that Spring can't construct `Bean1` until *after* `Bean2` has been created.  So it creates `Bean2` first, and you see that `x` is null in the `init()` block because `Bean1` hasn't been constructed yet to be able to set its value.

Later, `Bean1` will be constructed, its `init()` method will be called, and the value for `x` in `Bean2` will be correctly set.  But that happens long after `Bean2`'s `@PostConstruct` has already finished.

Comment: I'm not using Spring, can you rephrase your answer? Also, how to achieve passing a value of Bean1 to Bean2?

Comment: Regardless of the dependency injection framework that you're using, the result is the same.  Once the entire application is running, the value for `x` will be correct.  It just can't be correct in `Bean2`'s `@PostConstruct` method, because that method can only be run _after_ `Bean2` has been created, but _before_ `Bean1` has been created.  So it falls in a sort of "dead zone" where the code that initialized it cannot have been run yet.  But that code _will_ be run eventually, and the value will be good once the entire application has started up.

Comment: Is there a way to know in Bean1 that the injected instance of Bean2 was already created?

Comment: You know inside of `Bean1` that `Bean2` has already been created because the code would throw a `NullPointerException` on the line `bean2.setX(x);` if `bean2` were null.  The fact that the code isn't blowing up is proof that `Bean1` is getting created correctly (assuming that you're seeing the log messages coming from `Bean1`'s `init()` method).

Comment: If I can run `bean2.setX(x)` in bean1 without any exceptions that means that Bean2 is already created. Why the value of x is not set in Bean2? Also, is there a different way to achieve this?

Comment: It *is* set in `Bean2`!  It's just set _after_ `Bean2`'s `@PostConstruct`-annotated method is called.  The order that things happen in is: Bean2 is constructed --> Bean2's init() method is called (x is still null at this point) --> Bean1 is constructed --> Bean1's init() method is called, which sets x to "Some value" in Bean2.